# EmberJS: Change path to access a route

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-router

I have a `Router.map` defined to my application. I'm working with EmberJS AppKit architecture. https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit

I'd like to access to my page "profile" using the following path:
`http://localhost:8000/#/profile`

But, the name of my route differ to this path, because it's call `user-profile`, so I did this:

**router.js**

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend();

Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('user-profile', { path: 'profile'}, function() {
        //Some other things...
    });
});

export default Router;
```

**user-profile.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('user-profile');
    }
});
```

When I launch my application, Ember is telling me that `profile` route doesn't exist, even though I defined the path:

`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/profile' did not match any routes in your application`

Do you know what's wrong with my code at this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont use ember appkit but perhaps try with underscore, ie 'user_profile' and rename your file too. Just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score -1):

I would have to guess it is the way that you are designing your router and the namespace.

Typically a barebones Ember app requires:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('user-profile', { path: 'profile'}, function() {
  //Some other things...
});
```

In your example your router is not in the App namespace, or whatever your root object is named (It doesn't have to be 'App').  I would give this a try or maybe post more code if there are other factors I do not see here.

Also, typically you would name your route userProfile.  While i dont think the dasherized name is a problem, it doesn't follow Ember naming conventions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm working with Ember AppKit that doesn't require this namespace.

Comment: I see, well more code would still be helpful.  Did you define the actual route? `App.UserProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({})`  ?